# Why can't I delete a specific reference to a firebase task? I have the reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I have the key to a task but I cannot seem to remove it when I remove it's sibling key. When I create a task, I also create a duplicate of it with the same reference number. I'm setting the firebase ref to the specific task. What am I doing wrong?

```
        //get user feed
        var userRef = new Firebase("https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/users/" + user.uid + '/tasks/');
        var userList = $firebase(userRef);
        $scope.userList = userList.$asArray();

        //get activity feed
        var ref = new Firebase("https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/activity");
        var list = $firebase(ref);
        $scope.list = list.$asArray();

        $scope.addTask = function(task){
          var timestamp = moment().valueOf();
          $scope.list.$add({
            title: task.title,
            $priority: timestamp,
            timestamp: timestamp,
            tally:0
          }).then(function(ref){
            $scope.userList.$add({
              title: task.title,
              $priority: timestamp,
              timestamp: timestamp,
              tally:0,
              ref: ref.name()
            });
          });
        };

        $scope.deleteTask = function(task){
          $scope.userList.$remove(task);
          var ref = new Firebase("https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/activity/" + task.ref);
          $scope.list.$remove(ref);
        };
```

To add to the solution below:

When updating the task, I used

```
$scope.updateTask = function(task){
      $scope.userList.$save(task);
      var ref = new Firebase("https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/activity/" + task.ref);
      ref.update({title:task.title});
    };
```

The ref is saved from the promise when the task is initially created so it's the same ref. Apparently, you can't modify the object directly because it's a different object in each list. so $scope.list.$update($id) does not work in this case.

Comment: This will not work: `$scope.list.$remove(ref);`. The `$remove` method can accept either a `$id` or the item to remove. I don't think it can take a ref. That said: if you have a ref, you can simply call `ref.set(null)` on it to remove it from the Firebase.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Can you post this as an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work: `$scope.list.$remove(ref)`.

The `$remove` method can accept either a $id or the item to remove. I don't think it can take a ref.

When I need to remove an object from an array, I look it up like this:

```
list.$remove(list.$getRecord(id));
```

That said: if you have a ref, you can simply call `ref.set(null)` on it to remove it from the Firebase

Comment: It would be useful to know how I can access the $id. Assuming the $id is a value like -JYkQHOnim9st8ayPA7- , I do have access to that. But doing $remove() on it does not work.

Comment: What's strange is it looks like it SHOULD work looking at the documentation. Maybe I don't understand something properly. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebase-remove-key

Comment: I updated the original question with an expanded answer at the bottom.